# what is the difference between preg_match and ereg?

Tags: php, regex

I have a php page that gets `php_info()` and runs

```
ereg( '<body>(.*)</body>', $phpinfo, $regs );
```

This works just fine but since its deprecated I went ahead and updated it to `preg_match` and it looks like this

```
preg_match( '/<body>((?:.|\n)*)<\/body>/', $phpinfo, $regs );
```

but now its overloading the server every time I run that. It works on regexr.com so it shouldn't be THAT wrong.
What is the difference between the `ereg` and `preg_match` matches and how can I achieve this without blowing up the server?

What I'm trying to do is have a server page that displays `php_info` but with my normal menus and styling. Any alternatives would also be appreciated. Trying to stay away from iframe though.

Thanks

PS.: Regexr says the match is 105563 characters long

Comment: Ever consider using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead? Less overhead and more precision.

Comment: this sounds like a great option. i have 
                        $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($phpinfo);
   $temp =  $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
   foreach ($temp as $body) {
    echo $body->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
   }
but its just dumping the content fromt he tags without the html formatting. Also tried saveHTML but also no luck. WHat would be the correct output way to keep all the tags?

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments.  Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak the regex by adding the `s` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (which allows the dot metacharacter to match newlines), as in:

```
preg_match('/<body>.*<\/body>/s', $phpinfo, $regs);
```

This would leave you with the output in `$regs[0]` and should be as fast as possible for a regex -- clearly there is not much scope for improvement here.

If a regex is still too slow then a more performant option would be plain old string manipulation with `strpos`/`strrpos`/`substr`.

Answer (score 1):

As Machavity suggested you probably want t o try parsing the `phpinfo` content as a DOM. You can find a full example [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#109856), but this is a simplified data dump, which you can work out as you need:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $exts = get_loaded_extensions();
    phpinfo();
    $phpinfo = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    //print_r($phpinfo); 
    $html_str = $phpinfo;
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML($html_str);
    $html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;  
    $td = $html->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
     echo "<pre>";  
    foreach ($td as $value)   {
        print_r($value);
    }
?>
```

Comment: problem with this is that it strips the tags and i want to keep original formatting